# How to find the determinant of this $4\times4$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have been having some trouble finding the determinant of this matrix in the simplest way possible, without having so many terms in this case $24$ of them, the other way I thought would be to find an equivalent upper triangular matrix and multiply across the main diagonal, although I was not sure how to do this. What is the best approach to this?

$$\begin{pmatrix} (a_1-x) & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 \\ 0 & -x & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -x & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -x \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding along the first column (which has mostly zeroes), the determinant becomes
$$
(a_1-x)\left|\begin{matrix}-x&0&0\\1&-x&0\\0&1&-x\end{matrix}\right|
$$
However, this $3\times 3$ matrix is lower triangular, so its determinant is simply $-x^3$.

If you want to use row operations instead, then assuming $x\neq 0$, you can add $\frac1x$ times the second row to the third row, then take $\frac1x$ times the new third row and add that to the fourth row. This has the net effect of just removing the sub-diagonal $1$'s, giving you an upper triangular matrix.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain the process of how (a_1-x) has been factored out and the matrix is reduced to a 3*3, as I am a little confused where the a_2 to a_4 terms have gone.

Comment: @Nish How would you usually calculate the determinant?

Comment: If it's a 2*2 I'd take products along the diagonals and substract. For a 3*3 I'd use sarrus' rule. I'm not too sure about anything of an order greater than that other than that to be honest.

Comment: @Nish Then you really ought to look up the general formula. The two procedures you mention are both special cases. You were asked to find the determinant of a specific $4\times4$ matrix (an eigenvalue problem?) without being told the formula? That sounds very strange.

Comment: It was one of the questions in the textbook I am following - I will re-read to check if I have missed anything, although I don't recall seeing the formula. I will recap this to get some more insight regardless.

Comment: I have now understood the logic - cofactor expansion was a further topic that was ahead of this question for some reason, I have arrived at the same answer now. Thank you for your help.